# Neural Network not converging in multilabel classification task - TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am a beginner with TensorFlow and I really need some help with this task. I am doing some image pixels classification, and my problem is set this way:

my inputs is  array `X` that contain 20 values. These values represent 4 pixels (there are 5 values per pixel). My output is an array of 4 values, where each value can be either 1 or 0, and it means that the specific pixel may or may not have a specific characteristic. As you can imagine, it is possible that my `y` is of the form `y=[1, 0, 0, 1]`, so I can have multiple classes for each instance.

To perform this classification task, I organized a neural network with an input layer of 20 neurons, a hidden layer of 15, followed by another hidden layer of 10 and eventually there is an output layer of 4. The activation functions for the hidden layers are ReLU, and I applied 50% dropout to them. As a loss function to minimize, I use tensorflow's `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`, because it computes independent probabilities for each class, allowing to perform multilabel classification.

When I first attempted to train the network, I was getting all `NaN` results, because of (I think) an exploding gradient problem. This apparently solved after I lowered the learning rate.

My problem now is that this network is not converging at all, and I believe this is because something is wrong with the cost and activation functions that I am using.

Note: the input has been scaled with `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

n_inputs = 20
n_hidden1 = 15
n_hidden2 = 10
n_outputs = 4

dropout_rate = 0.5
learning_rate = 0.000000001


#This is a boolean value that indicates when to apply dropout
training = tf.placeholder_with_default(True, shape=(), name="training")

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(None, n_inputs), name ="X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, 4), name = "y")

with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden1, name="hidden1", activation = tf.nn.relu)
    hidden1_drop = tf.layers.dropout(hidden1, dropout_rate, training = training)

    hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, n_hidden2, name="hidden2", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    hidden2_drop = tf.layers.dropout(hidden2, dropout_rate, training = training)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2_drop, n_outputs, name="outputs")


with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = tf.cast(y, tf.float64), logits = tf.cast(logits, tf.float64))
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name = 'loss')


with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

n_epochs = 50
batch_size = 50
n_batches = 1000000

#training
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs): 
        for i in range(n_batches):
            X_batch = np.asarray(X_batches[i]).reshape(-1, 20)
            y_batch = np.asarray(y_batches[i]).reshape(-1, 4)
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict ={X: X_batch, y: y_batch, training:True})
            if (i % 10000) == 0:
                raws = logits.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, training:False})
                print("epoca = "+str(epoch))
                print("iterazione = "+str(i))
                print("accuratezza = "+str(get_global_accuracy_rate(raws, y_batch)))
                print("X = "+str(X_batch[0])+ " y = "+str(y_batch[0]))
                print("raws = "+str(raws[0])+" pred = " + str(get_prediction(raws[0])))


    save_path= saver.save(sess, "./my_model_final_1.ckpt")
```

Thank you so much in advance for any help!!

Comment: The lr is too low. I would suggest to remove dropout and have a normal lr (like 1e-4). If that works try adding dropout and see if that changes the behavior and work towards a solution from that

Comment: Also, from the fact that your labels are {0, 1}, consider of either having a softmax output with two sigmoid for each of the 4 outputs, or 4 sigmoids

Comment: Thank you so much! The idea of using a different activation function for each of the outputs seems very coherent with this task, could you please link me some tutorial or resource that can show me how to do it? Thank you again!

Comment: I'm always using the keras framework and not plain tensorflow, so I'm not 100% sure how to do that. I suggest to first understand what exactly you want to do and then look up some resources (like how to have multiple outputs, or how to create a softmax output). Also, your hidden_2 layer takes hidden_1 and not hidden_1_drop as an input. Was my suggestion of starting the network with an single layer and building it up when sure that works helped you in solving your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it still seems totally random. Certainly, the fact that hidden_2 was set to take the wrong input was not helping! Anyway, I will try to follow your suggestion and try to manipulate the output as you said. Thanks again, your help has been really appreciated!

Comment: No problem, happy to help